# jQuery Plugin - Strange click behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a short plugin for jQuery which will change the styles of the browser's in-built checkbox, so that it better fits with the theme.

Here is the plugin code:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.checkbox = function()
    {
        var uiBox = $('<span class="ui-checkbox" />'),
            that = this;

        uiBox.data('checkbox', this).insertAfter(this);
        this.hide();

        if(this.is(':disabled')) { uiBox.addClass('disabled'); }
        if(this.is(':checked')) { uiBox.addClass('checked'); }

        if(!uiBox.hasClass('disabled'))
        {
            uiBox.on('click', function() {
                var checkbox = $(this).data('checkbox');

                if(checkbox.is(':checked'))
                {
                    uiBox.removeClass('checked');
                    checkbox.attr('checked', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    uiBox.addClass('checked');
                    checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
            });
        }
    };

} (jQuery));
```

This code is then in turn called through the DOMReady handler using:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].ui').checkbox();
```

Everything works the first three times the 'checkbox' is clicked, but thereafter for some reason the code no longer executes the addition / removal of the necessary classes, and the original checkbox is never updated. Can anyone shed any light on the situation, and explain why this is happening?

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejM46/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `attr()` and not `prop()`, changing just the attribute and not the underlying property, change it to

```
checkbox.prop('checked', true);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejM46/3/)

Comment: Thanks. How come `attr()` works for the first three clicks, though?

Comment: It changes the attribute, so the checked state changes, but on the next click jQuery checks the property and not the attribute, and then the property is not the same as the attribute and is stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
 checkbox.prop('checked', 'checked');
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejM46/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this following code, I have tried it in your fiddle example it is working there,

`checkbox.prop('checked', true);`

Hope this Helps!